# Can you reference a reference?

Tags: c#, ref

Can you pass a reference to a reference sort of how passing a Control behaves?

I notice that when you pass a control into the constructor it actually passes a reference to that control and then if you assign another control to that control it is not copying the value but actually copying the reference itself! Why can't this be accomplished with regular variables or at least with the ref keyword?

For example...

```
public class Test : Form
{

Test()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
new Test2((Control)MyTextBox).ShowDialog();
}

}

public class Test2 : Form
{
Public Control x_
Test2(Control x)
{
x_=x;
InitializeComponent();
}
//use x_ somewhere in code to actually change x
}
```

What I don't understand is this works for Controls but it does not work for other variables. Now suppose I passed x as an int ref, there is no way I can pass the ref itself to x_? In the case of the Controls I don't even have to use ref which confuses me as to how exactly this occurs... I know how to pass variables back and forth through methods and parent/owner so my question is very specific to this particular quasi-pointer. Maybe I am misunderstanding how passing a Control behaves and if this is the case how would you structure an int exactly as Control is so that when you assign an int to an int like a Control it changes the original int just as it changes the original Control.

This works. Send is selfsame to send.

```
    new InputBox(((Label)sender)).ShowDialog();

    Label Send;
    public InputBox(Label send)
    {
     Send=send; 
    }
```

I want this to work in the same way. Send is now the same as send but not identically the same.

```
    new InputBox(((string)sender)).ShowDialog();

    string Send;
    public InputBox(string send)
    {
     Send=send; 
    }
```

I know how to pass variables between classes and such but I am asking to specifically have a string behave the same way Label is behaving when it is passed. When it is passed it is passed exactly like a pointer in the sense that I can make a variable equal the same instance of that variable. Why can't I make a string equal to the same instance of that string?

Comment: Could you past a code (or a pseudo-code), which fully describes your problem, instead of code, which works from your point?

Comment: I added code to demonstrate what I mean. If I declare 2 variables and make one equal to the other with a Label it will pass a reference but if I use a string it will pass a value and not a reference like Label will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the immutability of the strings in .NET is a thing, that confuses you.

The string **is** a reference type.
But it designed to be **immutable**.

This means, that you **can't modify** instances of `System.String`. Every time you're doing any operation, that should modify string, it just creates a **new** instance of string. Look at this sample:

```
class A
{
    private string someString;

    public A(string someString)
    {
        this.someString = someString;
    }

    public string SomeString
    {
        get { return someString; }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        someString = someString + "_abc";
    }
}


var sampleString = "Hello, world!";
var a = new A(sampleString);

Console.WriteLine(a.SomeString == sampleString); // prints 'true'

a.DoSomething();

Console.WriteLine(a.SomeString == sampleString); // prints 'false'
Console.WriteLine(sampleString); // prints 'Hello, world!'
Console.WriteLine(a.SomeString); // prints 'Hello, world!_abc'
```

Initially `sampleString` and `A.someString` are equal.

But after this line: `someString = someString + "_abc"` the field `A.someString` references **another** instance of string, because `+` operator has created a new instance, and assignment operator has assigned that instance to `A.someString`.

`System.String` can't behave like `Label`, because `Label` is mutable. Hence, `Label.Text = "Foobar";` doesn't create a new instance of label.

**UPD**.
If you want a mutable string, it already presents in FCL. This is [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class.

Comment: Can I make char[20] behave like Label? What exactly allows x_=x to pass a reference to label? Suppose I wanted to make my own String Datatype for example that passes the same way as Label using Char[20].

Comment: I use StringBuilder all the time. What makes StringBuilder able to be passed as a reference and int for example not able to be passed as a reference? For example suppose I wanted to make a simplified version of int or a simplified version of string. What exactly makes them have the ability to have multiple variable names equal/refer to the same value in memory space. Isn't StringBuilder acting as a pointer?

Comment: I have asked a new question on my profile. As this has brought up a new question to me. What exactly makes String designed to be immutable. What in the code allows the equal sign to just magically create a new instance? How can I create one of these magic instantiations without your knowledge classes? When you use an equal sign with StringBuilder it passes the instance but when you use an equal sign with String it magically creates a new instance.

Comment: I understand now, for some reason I couldn't wrap my head around the fact that an instance of String never actually changes. I understood that each change to String creates a new String but I never thought about how no part of String ever changes even a bit. One thing that throws me off is how the compiler magically converts test="test" to test=new String("test") I attribute that to my additional confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to understand is the difference between [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> **Value Types**
>
> A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory
> allocation.

They include types of

- All numeric data types
- Boolean, Char, and Date
- All structures, even if their members are reference types
- Enumerations, since their underlying type is always SByte, Short, Integer, Long, Byte, UShort, UInteger, or ULong

whereas

> **Reference Types**
>
> A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that
> holds the data.

they include types of

- String
- All arrays, even if their elements are value types
- Class types, such as Form
- Delegates

So further from [ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
> value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the
> parameter in the method is reflected in the underlying argument
> variable in the calling method.

That explains why you need to change the method signiture to use ref if you wish to have the changes to a value type propogate to the collung method.

Here is an example regarding the constructor calls

```
Control c1 = null;
Class1 cl1 = new Class1(c1); //c1 is still null after this call
Control c2 = null;
Class1 cl2 = new Class1(ref c2); //c2 is NOT null after this call

class Class1
{
    public Class1(Control c)
    {
        c = new Control();
    }

    public Class1(ref Control c)
    {
        c = new Control();
    }
}
```

Comment: If string and object are reference types then how come when I pass it through the constructor it behaves like a value type but when I pass a control through a constructor it behaves like a pointer/reference? What I mean is if you pass a Control it actually behaves like a pointer/reference because if I make another Control and make it equal to that Control it will refer to the same exact Control on the other form.

Comment: @CodeCamper - what do you mean it behaves like a value type?

Comment: I mean it behaves like a reference type.

Comment: @CodeCamper, I tested this, and it seems that all parameters passed to a constructor, is passed by value unless explicitly specified as ref.

Comment: Pass a Label for example and it will pass as a reference. Even if you assign it to a different Label variable. If I pass Label x and assign x_ = x, then x_ will contain the identical entity x is referring to. So it is behaving exactly like a pointer. So if I were to change x and x_ at the same time it would be changing the same address in memory. However if I box a label in an object it magically decides to pass it as a value.

Comment: @CodeCamper: `string` is a reference type, and it behaves like reference type in general. But `string` is designed as immutable type, that's why you can't change current instance and always getting a new instance, when making any modifications of `string`.

Comment: @CodeCamper, ref/pointer means that the parameter passed into the method/constructor is changed based on the changes inside the moethod/constructor

Comment: As one example how come when I pass a Label datatype it behaves exactly like a pointer? So that I could use the .Text property as way of having a non new instance of a string. I can create 3 variables a,b,c. a is the original Label I can say b=a and then c=b and a will be referring to the exactly identical thing a was referring to.

Comment: astander but when you pass a Label for example or any other Control it behaves exactly like a ref but even more it behaves exactly like a pointer. So that I can assign that variable to another variable and it still is pointing to the same memory space. Take my original question example you can pass Control as x and then assign x_ = x and then x_ is a pointer to what the original x was referring to. Why exactly is this happening?